# Return back to scroll position before Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use to jquery's ajax function to update a div on my page. Everything works fine, except my page is scrolled up.

I need somehow return to the updated div position. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your page shouldn't be scrolled up when you update a DIV.

Are you sure you're not using a link with `href='#'`? Because that will scroll you to the top of the page. In that case, make sure you `return false;` in the `onclick` part of the link.

Comment: It's used to be able to click a link without changing the page. '#' points to the page top, though. Just `return false` in the onclick function and it should go away.